# Read CSV in SharePoint to DataFrame and Upload back to Sharepoint as CSV

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint, office365

I have no issues loading the data using the sharepy module, but I am struggling to upload back to sharepoint.

If anyone has a textbook method (I don't mind using another module than sharepy), I'd be very grateful for the help.

I know posting code helps, but frankly there is not much to show, I've been trying bits and pieces found in various forms but I'm open to any library out there.